# Is it possible to send message from my account with interval in Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to send message from my own account with my nickname and profile (not from bot account) to any selected contact or group. How can I do that? I found bots with similar behaviour but messages are sent from bot account not from my profile which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is a so-called "userbot" or "selfbot", i.e. a bot that works with the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api) in contrast to the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). Searching for `Telegram userbot library <your preferred programming language>` should probably get you started.